# BZip decompress

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to decompress a BZip2 compressed string in MS SQL? Other than using `xp_cmdshell` and running it through bzip2.exe?

I have a string like `BZh41AY&SY3‹Ï¬€ !˜„]ÉáB@Î/>°` this is simply 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SQL CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) to do this - utilizing the [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class to decompress the value, or some third party library if you so choose.

Comment: Can you give me any pointers of where to begin? When Googling, the results I'm getting for CLR seem very complex. Even a URL would be good! Thanks!! @Oded

Comment: What's wrong with the _two_ links I already posted in my answer?

Comment: The first link is a Wikipedia article, the 2nd is the code to run *within* the CLR. I'm looking for how to make the CLR in the first place. I'd like to be able to do this directly in SQL.

Comment: @DannyBeckett - SQL CLR requires you to write some .NET code and use the mechanisms in SQL Server to import it and use it. My suggestion is not a pure SQL one (though seeing as someone wrote a [Mandelbrot set generator in T-SQL](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Stupid-Coding-Tricks-The-TSQL-Madlebrot.aspx), I am sure this is _possible_ to have a pure SQL solution).

Comment: @DannyBeckett - The Wikipedia article has several links to MSDN articles explaining in detail how to do use CLR in SQL.